# Is the feed that comes from Apple's RSS feed generator out of sync with the app store?

Tags: ios-appstore, rss

For example...

http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/toppaidapplications/limit=25/xml

Right now, for me, that feed shows Camera+ as being the number 3 app paid app. However, on the iphone app store at this moment, Camera+ is number 4 and Fruit Ninja: Puss in Boots is number 3. In the feed Puss in Boots is like 8 or 9.

The timestamp on items in the feed appears old. I thought maybe it was some sort of caching issue on my end, maybe it is, but I've tried running this from a clear browser.

Also if I go to http://feeds.appstorefeeds.com/appstorefeeds-TopPaidiPhoneApps it shows Camera+ as being number 3. Still caching maybe? I don't know. Anyone have any insights?

Comment: I'm guessing each <entry> is an app right? At 2011-10-20T15:24:12-07:00, the order is Words With Friends, Angry Birds, Camer+, Fruit Ninja. I have no idea if it is delayed but it is a possibility. Maybe it only updates a couple times a day.

Comment: Each <entry> is an app, correct.

Answer (score 1):

The "appstorefeeds.com" website is not associated with Apple. That appears to be a third-party site that creates its own feeds. My best guess is that it creates these feeds by scraping Apple's own feeds periodically. This type of operation is not something that can guarantee that all updates to Apple's own feeds will be updated live to "appstorefeeds.com".

Not even within Apple's own website infrastructure you get that type of live syncing. I have seen Apple's website out of sync with what is displayed in the charts within iTunes. If you want the closest to the latest information, you should probably check from within iTunes. Hope this helps.